# Create Combinations of Elements from a vector to give as input in a program

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a list of words. For example:

```
a=(ENCFF002CDP ENCFF002COQ ENCFF002DAJ ENCFF002DCM)
```

and I want to run all possible combinations of them and with a tool, like:

```
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002COQ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002COQ.intersected  
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DAJ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
```

etc. for all the possible combinations.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare -a encode_ids=(ENCFF002CDP ENCFF002COQ ENCFF002DAJ ENCFF002DCM)  

for (( i = 0; i < ${#encode_ids[@]}; ++i )); do
  for (( j = i + 1; j < ${#encode_ids[@]}; ++j )); do
    bedtools intersect -a "${encode_ids[i]}" -b "${encode_ids[j]}" \
      >"${encode_ids[i]}.${encode_ids[j]}".intersected
  done
done
```

The double loop above will give you all combinations of the given IDs, but will leave out combinations of the same ID with itself as well as avoiding combining ID `A` with `B` if the combination `B` with `A` has already been used.

The example array will result in the following `bedtool` runs:

```
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002COQ >ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002COQ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DAJ >ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DCM >ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DAJ >ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DCM >ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002DAJ -b ENCFF002DCM >ENCFF002DAJ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was trying to implement. I tested it!

Comment: very nice. native bash

Comment: @fusion.slope If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

**combo.py**

```
import sys
from itertools import combinations
for i in combinations(sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" "),2):
    print i[0],i[1]
```

**k.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=(ENCFF002CDP ENCFF002COQ ENCFF002DAJ ENCFF002DCM)

echo "${a[@]}" | python combo.py  | while IFS=" " read -r a b
do
    echo "bedtools intersect -a $a -b $b > $a.$b.intersected"
done
```

./k.sh should generate

```
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002COQ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002COQ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DAJ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DAJ > ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002DAJ -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002DAJ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
```

Comment: thanks but i do not see the point to write script in python and then  go back to shell.. thanks anyway

Comment: i tried. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a awk version.
If you need to run bedtools command in system then remove "echo" and "\\".

```
$ awk '{ 
        gsub(/[^0-9A-Z ]/,"")    # delete unneeded chars like "a=(", ")"
        for ( i=1; i < NF; i++) { 
            for (j=(i+1); j <= NF; j++) { 
                system("echo bedtools intersect -a "$i" -b "$j" \\> "$i"."$j".intersected")
            } 
        }  
}' file

bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002COQ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002COQ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DAJ > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002CDP -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002CDP.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DAJ > ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DAJ.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002COQ -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002COQ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
bedtools intersect -a ENCFF002DAJ -b ENCFF002DCM > ENCFF002DAJ.ENCFF002DCM.intersected
```

Comment: could you explain please briefly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would then have to `eval` the output from that, right? To actually execute the commands I mean.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use system function